# Authorize.net ARB - Email Notifications - Failed CSV through email

Tags: php, email, authorize.net

When Authorize.net ARB has a failed transaction for a customer, it will send an email with successful.csv and failed.csv. I've been through the entire integration guide, though I feel like I'm missing something. Is there a way to get a bulk list of people who failed transactions without trying to automate it using email?

Comment: cant you just ask them? they do have support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a bulk list but you can automate it. You can use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/) to be notified every time a payment is made or failed and act accordingly (including doing nothing).

Comment: Silent post was where I was headed.  Thanks once again John